Is it getting harder and harder to earn reputation?
In the past, people were able to gain reputation by answering easy questions. Now when those questions are posted, they become duplicates and answering them is forbidden.
I suspect that easy-to-answer questions will be exhausted, making it harder for new users to get reputations and privileges.

There is also opportunity to earn reputation by asking good Questions.  The goal of learning mathematics should drive these posts, as having a lasting benefit.

Yes, it is harder to get reputation these days. Reputation is intended to help motivate people to create a good web site, and the way reputation was awarded was played around with in earlier days of the site to make it most effective. It could probably use some more attention now that it's 12+ years old, but current management is more interested in AI than building community. That said, you can still get a lot from math.se by just reading Q's and A's, even if you don't earn rep. I agree that earning rep is fun, and it kinda sucks that it's gotten harder to do.

I would have agreed with your sentiment if you've said that  standard easy questions are exhausted. In any case, I do not understand what is the problem here that you are trying to resolve.

There is a decent chance of earning a good amount of reputation if you post inventive and original solutions to easy-to-answer or somewhat moderate questions, especially those that are recent.

I think the answer is yes.  The site disproportionately rewards standard answers to easy / standard questions.  The audience that is capable of and interested in evaluating things off the beaten path is a lot smaller.

Not too long ago on [meta.se]: Is reputation harder to earn in 2024?

I'll say! I've barely earned any for years now.

(From my comment on a deleted answer) fyi: users can still quickly gain rep in tags where dupes are $\rm\color{#c00}{rarely\ closed}$ such as calculus and geometry, cf. table below. But this is much more difficult in the topmost tags, which have $10:!\times$ more effort involved in dupe management. This counts only non-deleted dupes, ranging from $2022!−!2024$, i.e. post EoQS. $\ \ $

$$\begin{array}{c|l}  \rm %dupes & \rm tag\  \hline   16.5&\rm gcd\  12.7&\rm divisibility\  12.6&\rm mod\  9.5&\text{elementary-number-theory}\  2.5&\color{#c00}{\text{real-analysis}}\  2.2&\color{#c00}{\rm calculus}\  1.2&\color{#c00}{\rm probability}\  0.9&\color{#c00}{\rm geometry} \end{array}\qquad$$

Yes, absolutely. Old-timers (who already have enough rep not to care anymore) mostly argue this doesn't matter. But newcomers see the reputation figures very prominently, and they get frustrated.
The fact is, at one point, the twin goals of participation (let's say, asking and answering questions that come up naturally) and curation (let's say, cleaning up bad questions and answers, upvoting good questions and answers, adding tags, closing duplicates, etc. so that the library of good questions is complete and useful) worked in tandem.
Curation closed out bad questions and categorized good ones, so answerers could more easily find interesting questions to answer, and askers could feel confident that their questions would get noticed.
But over time things changed. The chance that your question had already been asked (in some form, five years ago) started to rise and rise. You'd be chastised for not searching correctly, although in fact it's fairly difficult to do, and your question would be closed. Answerers, likewise, would find a lack of approachable questions, and get bored. This isn't because anybody did anything wrong exactly, it's just a consequence of accumulating questions over the course of years.
This is good for lurkers and googlers, who just want the answer to their question as quickly as possible. But now the twin pillars of the site -- let's say, curators and participants -- feel like they're in conflict with each other. It's a problem. Obviously you need both. If curators stop their work (which often feels thankless), the site gets overrun with duplicates, low effort questions, bad answers, spam, unsearchable content, and so on. If the participants stop their work, the content calcifies and the site feels stagnant.
I have no idea what the solution is. People complain about stackexchange focusing on AI, but I'm not sure what they could be doing instead.

Very nice answer. I will just add that I'm finding the model of "we're building a body of high-quality questions and answers" seems to be ossifying. I think we'd be better thinking of ourselves as a very good library with very good librarians. Because all the knowledge is already in a book somewhere, and StackExchanges have worked the best for me when my questions were read by someone who could see my issue, and knew where to find the answer, i.e. a good librarian. But this requires emphasizing the community over the IP, and that doesn't happen much these days on the Internet.

Summary The site has evolved from population to organization mode, and SE gamification motivation does not work well in organization mode.

That sounds like your take on things, not a summary of what was written in the answer.

@JonathanZ If you can devise a better one sentence summery then let's hear it.

It's a pretty short answer, it describes multiple aspects of a complicated situation, and it concludes with "I have no idea what the solution is". I don't think it needs a one sentence summary, I'm not sure anyone can come up with a good one, and it clearly doesn't come to the conclusion that your comment does. I'm all in favor of people presenting their takes, analyses, and proposed solutions (that's what I did in my comment), but labeling one's own take as a "summary" of someone else's answer when they are very clearly different doesn't seem cricket.

At the end of the day, it doesn't really matter whether it is easier or harder today.  Comparison is the thief of joy -- comparing yourself to others (including others in the past) just leads to needless negative feelings, resentment, inability to see the good that you have today, etc.
Instead, I believe what matters is whether it is too hard, too easy, or just right today.  What matters is the absolute, not the relative.  Perhaps it was too easy in the past, and the difficulty right now is fine.   Overall, my sense is that it's not too hard to earn reputation today.
And in any case, reputation is a bit of a distraction.  What does it really matter how much reputation you have?  I suggest you care more about whether you are helping people, and making the world a better place.  In my experience, that way leads to greater satisfaction and pride in your work, and will guide you to spending your time in ways that matter.

It matters because it says who has access to administrative tools on the site

@Brian Actually it matters little since almost all such actions can be recommended in the CURED chat room where they can be performed by others (and this is actually a good thing  since  it means they will be reviewed by more experienced users)

Reputation matters a lot.... I have constraint myself plenty of times in the past of doing bounties, because I will lose enough point to lose the privilege of starting chats

A Solution to the Problem of Reputation for New Users
-----------------------------------------------------

I have a suggestion for a new feature on our website that could enhance user engagement, make problem-solving more interactive, and solve the problem of reputation for users like us. Here's the idea:
Quiz System with Reputation Points:


Create a quiz-like setup using our library of math problems categorized into Easy, Medium, Challenging, and Expert levels.
Solving Easy problems could award +2 reputation points.
Medium problems might grant +5 to +7 reputation, depending on difficulty.
Challenging problems might grant +10 to +12 reputation, depending on difficulty
Expert (God-level) problems could yield +20 reputation for users who solve them.


Subtopic-Based Quizzes


Quizzes can be further categorized into various subtopics of mathematics, such as Number Theory, Precalculus-Algebra, Geometry, and
more
This specialization would allow users to focus on areas of their interest or expertise, making the quizzes more engaging and
personalized.


Badges for Achievements:


Users could earn badges for excelling in specific subtopics or achieving certain milestones, such as completing a series of
Expert-level problems.
These badges would add an extra layer of motivation and recognition, especially since earning badges has become increasingly
challenging, similar to reputation points.


Personalized Problem Selection:


To prevent repetition and ensure fairness, the system could track a user’s interaction history. This way, the questions presented will
always be new and outside their history, minimizing the chances of
cheating.


This feature could encourage users to engage more actively, improve their problem-solving skills, and gain reputation and badges for their efforts. It would also add an exciting competitive element to the platform.
Looking forward to hearing thoughts on this suggestion and ways it can be refined!

I am here to discuss the problems which is leading to negative votes to my answer.

On meta, votes may also mean agreement/disagreement. I think your answer is being downvoted primarily because people disagree with your suggestion. This is a natural thing that can happen when you put forward an opinion: others may disagree. For instance, I don't think this is a good idea and I've downvoted your answer.

@HankScorpio Can you please tell me the reason? so that I can understand my failure

It doesn't align with what the site is trying to be: a repository of knowledge via high-quality questions and answers. (It also doesn't align with the goal of people getting their math questions answered, which is the main competing vision for the site.)
